# Is it more pythonic to use in operator vs or operator

Tags: python

Which of these statements is more pythonic? If I added more comparisons, would one become more useful than the other?

```
if(card3 == game_data['card1'] or card3 == game_data['card2'])
```

Or

```
if (card3 in [game_data['card1'],  game_data['card2']])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For only two comparisons either one is okay.  But the second way is more Pythonic as it more naturally extends to larger numbers of comparisons.  In addition, as Perkins mentions, if `game_data` is a dict and "card1" and "card2" are the only keys, then you could use `if card3 in game_data.values()`.

The overhead of creating a list is negligible for any number of cases that you would be able to type out by hand.  If you have too many to type out by hand, you'll have them stored in some sort of container and you can use `in` on that container.

The only reason to stick with `or` for large numbers of comparisons would be if the objects you're comparing against are unusual objects for which equality testing is computationally expensive, and you need to rely on the short-circuit behavior of `or` to test them in a specially motivated order.  This would be an unusual situation, though.

Answer (score -1):

Or.  It'll be faster too.  The other way creates a list and then throws it away, which is wasteful and less clear.  If there are only two keys, you can do `if card3 in game_data.values()`, but otherwise use `or`.